# Логика работы условия и , или на javascript

Tags: javascript, if

не пойму что я делаю не так, не понимаю логику работы условия.

Мне нужно два сценария:

1. оба числа больше  0.7
2. хотя бы одно из двух чисел не больше 0.2

Пишу следующий код но он не отрабатывает как нужно, что я упускаю?

```
const randomNumber = Math.random(); // produces random number between 0 (including) and 1 (excluding)

const separateRandomNumber = Math.random();

const condition07 = 0.7;
const condition02 = 0.2;

if (randomNumber && separateRandomNumber > condition07) {
  alert("scenario 1");
} else if (randomNumber || separateRandomNumber < condition02) {
  alert("scenario2");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const randomNumber = Math.random();
const separateRandomNumber = Math.random();

const condition07 = 0.7;
const condition02 = 0.2;

if (randomNumber > condition07 && separateRandomNumber > condition07) {
  console.log("scenario 1", randomNumber, separateRandomNumber);
} else if (randomNumber < condition02 || separateRandomNumber < condition02) {
  console.log("scenario 2", randomNumber, separateRandomNumber);
} else {
  console.log("no scenario", randomNumber, separateRandomNumber);
}
```

Comment: получается , сгрупировал не верно

Comment: @spectre_it Нет, условия, написанные Вами, вообще означают совершенно другое.

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотели объединить с помощью **И** две переменные (как если бы это были однородные члены предложения) и передать их оператору сравнения **БОЛЬШЕ**. Но выражения в языках программирования так не работают.

В первую очередь нужно понять, что логическое **И** в языках программирования не создаёт перечисление, как союз **И** в естественных языках, таких как русский или английский. Это Булев оператор. Он возвращает не список  из поданных на вход операндов, а логическое значение *true* или *false*. Булевы операторы применяются только к логическим значениям. Если на вход булева оператора подаётся не логическое значение, то есть 2 варианта того, что произойдёт. Если язык программирования поддерживает неявное (автоматическое) приведение типов, то значение будет приведено к булеву типу по правилам, принятым в этом языке. Если язык не поддерживает неявное приведение типов, то будет ошибка.

Вот Ваше условие: `if (randomNumber && separateRandomNumber > condition07)`. Как оно может быть разобрано интерпретатором *Js*? У оператора сравнения `>` приоритет выше, чем у оператора булевого **И** `&&`. Поэтому *Js* сначала вычислит результат выражения `separateRandomNumber > condition07`. Это будет *true* или *false*. А затем к этому результату и `randomNumber` будет применено логическое **И** (`&&`). Но `randomNumber` - это не переменная Булева типа, а число. Поскольку *Js* поддерживает неявное приведение типов, значение `randomNumber` будет неявно приведено к Булеву типу по правилу: 0 преобразуется в *false*, другие числа преобразуются в *true*. Таким образом, *Js* не выдаст ошибки, выражение будет вычислено. Но результат будет явно не тем, который Вам нужен)

Как составить условие правильно, Вам уже написали в ответе выше.